# Error on one page that does not appear anywhere else

Tags: arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi so my wordpress site has just started acting up, I am not sure if its an update that has caused this but only on this one page I am getting this error regarding

Notice: Array to string conversion in /customers/c/1/7/veganantics.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/StoreApi/Schemas/ImageAttachmentSchema.php on line 95

I can't seem to find the issue, I have tried replacing the file with a new core file and the error is still there, would really appreciate some help

This is the page: https://veganantics.co.uk/vegan-gifts/

Thank you
Ash

Comment: it's a plugin conflict. disable all plugins and enable one by one and check error.

Answer (score 0):

The theme, a plugin or some custom code is probably using the `wp_calculate_image_sizes` filter and returning an `array` instead of a `string`.

Do a text search on your install and look for `wp_calculate_image_sizes`. The function that you need to find will look similar to

```
add_filter('wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'something');
```

Explanation:

[ImageAttachmentSchema.php on line 95](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woo-gutenberg-products-block/trunk/src/StoreApi/Schemas/ImageAttachmentSchema.php#L95) is calling `wp_get_attachment_image_sizes` which must be a string.

[wp_get_attachment_image_sizes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1448) is returning `wp_calculate_image_sizes( $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id )` which again must be a string.

[wp_calculate_image_sizes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1482) returns a filtered value, and that's the only place where such an error (`array` instead of a `string`) can happen. So, if the filter incorrectly returns an `array`, it bubbles up to the function that you see in the error log.